# Wrong sum of values from list of dict

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, append

From a JSON file, with a list of dict, I'm trying to get data for each user and use them to create e new dict. Since each user has multiple objects, I'm interacting through them with a for loop. The start json looks like this:

```
[{
  "obj_id": "bfyguwc9971",
  "user_id": 3,
  "investment": 34,
  "profit": 67
},
{
  "obj_id": "sdklgnv820",
  "user_id": 12,
  "investment": 71,
  "profit": 43
}]
```

The JSON contains hundreds of these dictionaries, what I'm trying to achieve is to have a final dict with the avg investment and profit for each user.
Here is the code I'm running:

```
import json
with open('user_data.json','r') as f:
    user_data = json.load(f)

users_id = []
users_dict = {}
obj_count = 0
investment_list = []
profit_list = []

for i in user_data:
    if i['user_id'] not in users_id:
        users_id.append(i['user_id'])

for a in users_id:
    users_dict[a] = {}
    for i in user_data:
        if i['user_id'] == a:
            obj_count += 1
            users_dict[a]['Objects'] = obj_count
            investment_list.append(i['investment'])
            profit_list.append(i['profit'])
    avg_investment = (sum(investment_list)/len(investment_list))
    users_dict[a]['avg_investment'] = avg_investment
    avg_profit = (sum(profit_list)/len(profit_list))
    users_dict[a]['avg_profit'] = avg_profit
print(users_dict)
```

The problem occurs at the output, instead of giving me the right single values for each user, it give me back the first user values right and then it continues to add values for the next users, so the last user will have all the previous values calculated for the other users. What am I doing wrong? Thanks on advance for helping me!

Comment: It will be a lot easier for others to help you if you provide the _output_ you get and the _output_ you expect

Comment: 1.  Reinitialize the investment_list and profit_list for every new 'a' will solve your problem.  2.  Better variable nameing even for loop index is useful and preferred.